# converting column item into its own column python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

i have a data frame that looks like this

```
column1  column2

rabbit   fluffy  
dog      cute
cat      tabby
```

i would like to make each value in `column1` into its own column, with values in `column2` as the observation for that column.

So the end result desired is:

```
rabbit dog  cat

fluffy cute tabby
```

What is the proper syntax in python to accomplish this task?

Comment: `df.set_index('column1').T`

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([df['column2'].tolist()], columns=df['column1'].tolist())
```

If more columns:

```
cols = df.pop('column1').tolist()
data = df.values.reshape(len(df.columns), -1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) with data cleaning - [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('column1').T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df1)
   rabbit   dog    cat
0  fluffy  cute  tabby
```